# How to sort product by product category php

Tags: php, html, database, categories, store

I have a problem with this part of my code.I have column with categories of a products in database of my site, but I can't sort them by this categories. I want to sort them before they show in the store page! I want to show only products with category - women or only with category man! This is my code for now and i don't know what to do. Please, help me! This is import in bigger html code!

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM woman_t_shirts ORDER BY id ASC");
if($results){

$products_item = '<div class="row shop_wrapper">';
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 ">
                                        <div class="single_product"> <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
                                            <div class="product_thumb">
                                                <a class="primary_img" href="product-details.html"><img src="assets/img/product/exillys/{$obj->product_img_name}" alt=""></a>
                                                <a class="secondary_img" href="product-details.html"><img src="assets/img/product/exillys/{$obj->product_img_name}" alt=""></a>
                                                <div class="product_action">
                                                    <div class="hover_action">
                                                       <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                       <label>
        <input type="hidden" name="product_qty" value="1" size="2" maxlength="2"/>
  </label>

  <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
  <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
                                                        <div class="action_button">
                                                            <ul>

                                                                <li><button type="submit" class="add_to_cart" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 16pt"></i><br></button></li>         <br><br>
                                                                <li><a href="wishlist.html" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>


                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                   </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="quick_button">
                                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_box" title="quick_view">+ quick view</a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="double_base">
                                            <div class="product_sale">
                                                <span>-7%</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="label_product">
                                                <span>new</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product_content grid_content">
                                        <h3><a>{$obj->product_name}</a></h3>
                                        <span class="current_price">{$obj->price}</span>
                                        <span class="old_price">{$obj->price_not_sale}</span>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="product_content list_content">
                                        <h3><a>{$obj->product_name}</a></h3>
                                        <div class="product_price">
                                            <span class="current_price">{$obj->price}</span>
                                        <span class="old_price">{$obj->price_not_sale}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product_desc">
                                            <p>{$obj->product_desc}</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
EOT;
      }             }
$products_item .= '</div>';
echo $products_item;
?>
```

Comment: It is hard to guess how is your database, so, please, post also the table's structure . By any means, I would suggest to user ORDER BY into your sql query. More info on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-order-by-clauses.html

Comment: That is a structure of a table which i want to use. I want to sort pruduct by product_catg in the page with first code.

Comment: use 'ORDER BY  product_catg' instead id